# How to make a simple VR video player by Google CardBoard Android SDK

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, google-cardboard

Im following as what Mog suggest in the post:

[How to create VR Video player using Google Cardboard SDK for Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30277895/how-to-create-vr-video-player-using-google-cardboard-sdk-for-unity/30405578#30405578)

Here's my code snippet

1.
In the MainActivity's `onSurfaceCreated()` method , I initialise a texture and bind it to GL, and create a surface and a mediaplayer associated to them.

[image]

2. in the `onNewFrame()` method, I update the texture as what Mog said in the post

[image]

I saved my short video as small.mp4 in the raw folder, however , after I start my app the two sides are blank, and the video's sound is actually playing.

Comment: Qing, is your code working now?

Comment: yes, it was solved already, you can checkout my repo here :https://github.com/richardissuperman/VRvideoPlayer

Comment: may you please help me in streaming live video using opengl and Cardboard

Comment: im not familiar with live streaming video, but the concept is already there in the sample,you just have to render your content in the Sufrace object,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing a similar problem in order to get this done I've used the great [RajawaliVR library](https://github.com/Rajawali/RajawaliVR/).

The code I used:

```
    streamingTexture = new StreamingTexture("video", mediaPlayer);
    Material material = new Material();
    material.setColor(0);

    try {
        material.addTexture(texture);
    } catch (ATexture.TextureException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    Sphere sphere = new Sphere(50, 64, 32);
    sphere.setScaleX(-1);
    sphere.setMaterial(material);
    getCurrentScene().addChild(sphere);
```

Comment: hey Danny whats the StreamingTexture ? where it is defined

Comment: StreamingTexture can be found in the package: org.rajawali3d.materials.textures
Make sure you've the latest Rajawali version

Comment: Hi, @danny11 the input for Rajawali should be a 360 degree video. Is it possible to create video player for google cardboard for normal videos?