# Split normal android screen to Google cardboard view

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, google-cardboard, 360-virtual-reality

I have created a video player using OpenGl in android and it works fine. I used the following tutorial (https://www.virag.si/2014/03/rendering-video-with-opengl-on-android/).

Now I want to create same app for Google Cardboard. I searched it on internet and found out following queries and a Rajawali Renderer. ([How to make a simple VR video player by Google CardBoard Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31945630/how-to-make-a-simple-vr-video-player-by-google-cardboard-android-sdk))

Now first of all Rajawali latest code is not working. So, if anyone has a working code please suggest.

Second thing is that Rajawali requires 360 degree input. But I want to view my normal videos using Google cardboard. So, I want to learn how to split my screen of Video player, so that I can see the output in Google cardboard.

Also, how to split any normal android screen so that we can see the output in Google cardboard?

Comment: Creating image for vr is relatively simple you render side by side on the screen two almost same images and deal with distortion. Look at this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B7qrgrrHry0)

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can download cardboard SDK from here:
https://developers.google.com/vr/android/download

On git, there are some samples,

https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/sdk-simplevideowidget/src/main/java/com/google/vr/sdk/samples/simplevideowidget/SimpleVrVideoActivity.java

this is for using a video in "simplepanoview" that is a custom VR view as you can see here: https://developers.google.com/vr/android/samples/vrview#vr_view_sample_apps

In the sample is used `loadVideoFromAsset("video.mp4")` this method is called in `AsyncTask`.
When the video is loaded (or if it fails) starts `onLoadSuccess` (or `onLoadError`).

You can find very good documentation here: https://developers.google.com/vr/android/reference/com/google/vr/sdk/widgets/video/VrVideoView

Hope this helps you, let me know, good luck!