# How to build VR video player for iOS in Unity with Google Cardboard SDK

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30277895/how-to-create-vr-video-player-using-google-cardboard-sdk-for-unity) discusses generally how to build a VR video player using the Google Cardboard SDK for Unity.

I have been trying to get this to work on iOS, without much luck. One question I have is, what version of Unity is required? The user manual for Easy Movie Texture mentions that Unity Pro is required for iOS. Have people only had success with that, or has anybody gotten it to work with Unity Personal?

Answer (score 2):

Have you visited [this page](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/unity/get-started-ios)?

> Unity version: The Cardboard SDK will only work with iOS if you are running Unity 4.5 or better.

Unity 5 Personal Edition has all features as you can see it [here](https://unity3d.com/get-unity).

If you have specific problem, rather than "not working", make it clear.

Comment: You might want to actually read my question before dismissing it.  I was not asking about getting the cardboard sdk working.  I was asking about getting easymovietexture working.  That is a specific problem, and your answer did not address that at all.

Comment: To be fair, I could have made that more clear, though I f you'd read the link I referenced, it would have been much more clear.

Comment: So you are asking about plugin from asset store https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10032? Have you contacted with the author? Have you tried using it and something is not working? So show us what have you tried. With Unity 5 Pro and Personal have the same functionality so it shouldn't have matter.